# virtuemart with joomla show multiple images

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

When we upload multiple images using the media uploader, they don't appear as multiple views on the product page - no matter which category flypage we choose.

Answer (score 1):

I think putting the images on the description itself is the only solution I've worked with when working with multiple images on Virtuemart.com

Answer (score 0):

why not just add the images in the product discription. The WYSIWYG editor will alow you to insert many pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to modify your flypage to have multiple images